# Leave order intact when extracting from a named vector

Tags: r

So if I have:

```
>  g<-c(1,5,2,4,6)
> names(g)<-c("josh","daniel","john", "luke", "bill")
> g
  josh daniel   john   luke   bill 
     1      5      2      4      6 
> 
> g[c("john", "daniel", "bill")]
  john daniel   bill 
     2      5      6
```

Is it possible to return the values as they are originally ordered in g, i.e. (daniel then john then bill) WITHOUT using a sort function?

Thanks!
-Josh

Comment: I changed your title to better describe your situation; if you really  meant for this question to address matrices, feel free to edit it back, but you should probably add some examples that actually use matrices.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`%in%` will do this for you:

```
> g[names(g) %in% c("john", "daniel", "bill")]
daniel   john   bill 
     5      2      6
```